# jQuery extend overwrites wrong values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery `extend` in a plugin to overwrite the default parameters. However, I have a problem.

Here's my default settings array:

```
slider.settings = {
            background: {
                animation : {
                    direction : 'horizontal',
                    increment : 15 //can be any number
                }
            }
        }
```

Now, I want to overwrite the `direction` parameter. Here's the array that I will merge with using `extend`:

```
    settingsToOverwrite = {
        background:{
            animation:{
                direction:'vertical'
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, I merge the two:

```
slider.settings = $.extend(slider.settings, options)
```

I can see that the *direction* value has been updated. However, *increment* is no longer there. I know that to avoid this problem I could only set parameters at the first level but I see more code clarity in doing my way. Is there a way to do so ? If not, I will change everything to be only one level deep.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default, `jQuery.extend()` only compares the immediate properties, performing a "*shallow merge*." Since both objects have `background`, it simply takes the entire `background` from the 2nd object.

But, [pass a `true`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN) as the 1st argument, and `jQuery.extend()` will perform a "*deep merge*."

```
slider.settings = $.extend(true, slider.settings, options);
```

---

Also, since the 1st `Object` is the `target` and will be both modified and `return`'d, you can update `slider.settings` with just:

```
$.extend(true, slider.settings, options);
```

And, if you'd rather have a `new Object` from the merge, you'll have to create it yourself:

```
slider.settings = $.extend(true, {}, slider.settings, options);
```

Comment: I noticed that `var newObj = $.extend(Obj1,Obj2);` will also modify the content of `Obj1` which is not desired which stores fallback values but adding a `{}` won't. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

You are right, this is obviously happening because jQuery's extend is "shallow extending" the object.. thus replacing the entire "animation" property.

To fix this, use your brandy dandy deepExtend:

```
Object.deepExtend = function(destination, source) {
  for (var property in source) { // loop through the objects properties
    if (typeof source[property] === "object") { // if this is an object
      destination[property] = destination[property] || {};
      Object.deepExtend(destination[property], source[property]); // recursively deep extend
    } else {
      destination[property] = source[property]; // otherwise just copy
    }
  }
  return destination;
};
```

You can use it as follows:

```
slider.settings = Object.deepExtend(slider.settings, options);
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what I would do with slider.settings ? I mean I don't know how I would use this function. Thank you.

Comment: just added to answer :)

Comment: This is nice but I would avoid `arguments.callee` as it will throw an error in strict mode. Just use a named function expression for recursion.